# WebGL shapes disappearing

Tags: webgl

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/354qA.png)   *[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ykf6.png)* 
When im rendering using requestAnimationFrame , Sometimes it generates only 1 circle or a big circle and small circles where both these circles need to have same radius.
As you can see i am increasing the radius of circles during the requireanimationframe.
if i have a r value of greater than 1 it renders the background circle and other small circles.
if the r value is much smaller it  doesnt render the background and renders an animated circle

```
var vertexShaderText =
      [
      'uniform vec2 u_resolution;',
      '',
      'attribute vec2 a_position;',
        '',
        'void main()',
        '{',
        '',
        'vec2 clipspace = a_position / u_resolution * 2.0 -1.0 ;',
        '',
        'gl_Position = vec4(clipspace *vec2(2.5,-1.3) , 0, 1);',
        '}'
      ].join("\n");
      var fragmentShaderText =
      [
      'precision mediump float;',
      '',
        'void main(void)',
        '{',
        '',
        'gl_FragColor = vec4(0.75, 0.85, 0.8, 0.85);',
        '',
        '}'

      ].join("\n");
        var fragmentShaderText0 =
      [
      'precision mediump float;',
      '',
        'void main(void)',
        '{',
        '',
        'gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.85);',
        '',
        '}'

      ].join("\n");
          var fragmentShaderText1 =
      [
      'precision mediump float;',
      '',
        'void main(void)',
        '{',
        '',
        'gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);',
        '',
        '}'

      ].join("\n");
            var fragmentShaderText2 =
      [
      'precision mediump float;',
      '',
        'void main(void)',
        '{',
        '',
        'gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0);',
        '',
        '}'

      ].join("\n");
            var fragmentShaderText3 =
      [
      'precision mediump float;',
      '',
        'void main(void)',
        '{',
        '',
        'gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5,0.0,0.0,1.0);',
        '',
        '}'

      ].join("\n");
            var fragmentShaderText4 =
      [
      'precision mediump float;',
      '',
        'void main(void)',
        '{',
        '',
        'gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.5,0.0,1.0);',
        '',
        '}'

      ].join("\n");
            var fragmentShaderText5 =
      [
      'precision mediump float;',
      '',
        'void main(void)',
        '{',
        '',
        'gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.5,1.0);',
        '',
        '}'

      ].join("\n");
            var fragmentShaderText6 =
      [
      'precision mediump float;',
      '',
        'void main(void)',
        '{',
        '',
        'gl_FragColor = vec4(0.2,0.0,0.0,1.0);',
        '',
        '}'

      ].join("\n");
            var fragmentShaderText7 =
      [
      'precision mediump float;',
      '',
        'void main(void)',
        '{',
        '',
        'gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.2,0.0,1.0);',
        '',
        '}'

      ].join("\n");
            var fragmentShaderText8 =
      [
      'precision mediump float;',
      '',
        'void main(void)',
        '{',
        '',
        'gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.2,1.0);',
        '',
        '}'

      ].join("\n");
            var fragmentShaderText9 =
      [
      'precision mediump float;',
      '',
        'void main(void)',
        '{',
        '',
        'gl_FragColor = vec4(0.2,0.2,0.0,1.0);',
        '',
        '}'

      ].join("\n");
    var uni = function(){
      var canvas = document.getElementById("game-surface");
      var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
      console.log("This is working");




      var vertextShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
      var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

      gl.shaderSource(vertextShader,vertexShaderText);
      gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader,fragmentShaderText);

      gl.compileShader(vertextShader);
      gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

      if(!gl.getShaderParameter(vertextShader,gl.COMPILE_STATUS)){
        console.error("Error with vertexshader",gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertextShader));
        return;
      }
      if(!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader,gl.COMPILE_STATUS)){
        console.error("Error with fragmentShader",gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
        return;
      }



      var program =gl.createProgram();
      gl.attachShader(program,vertextShader);
      gl.attachShader(program,fragmentShader);
      gl.linkProgram(program);
      gl.useProgram(program);
      if(!gl.getProgramParameter(program,gl.LINK_STATUS)){
        console.error("Error linking program",gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
        return;
      }
      gl.validateProgram(program);
      if(!gl.getProgramParameter(program,gl.VALIDATE_STATUS)){
        console.error("Error validating",gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
      }

      var circle = {x: 150, y:75, r: 45};
        var ATTRIBUTES = 2;
        var numFans =32;
        var degreePerFan = (2* Math.PI) / numFans;
        var vertexData = [circle.x, circle.y];

        for(var i = 0; i <=numFans; i++) {
          var index = ATTRIBUTES * i + 2; // there is already 2 items in array
          var angle = degreePerFan * (i+1000);
          vertexData[index] = circle.x + Math.cos(angle) * circle.r;
          vertexData[index + 1] = circle.y + Math.sin(angle) * circle.r;
        }

        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*64);





        var vertexDataTyped = new Float32Array(vertexData);

        var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexDataTyped, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        var resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_resolution");
        gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);

        var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, ATTRIBUTES * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, 0);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vertexData.length/ATTRIBUTES);

    /////
      var randomBacteria = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1;
      console.log(randomBacteria);
      for(var k = 0;k <randomBacteria;k++){
        var b_colors = this["fragmentShaderText"+k];

        gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader,b_colors);
        gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
        var program1 =gl.createProgram();
      gl.attachShader(program1,vertextShader);
      gl.attachShader(program1,fragmentShader);
      gl.linkProgram(program1);
      gl.useProgram(program1);

      var randomEven = Math.floor(Math.random()*67/2)*2;
      var check = vertexData[randomEven];
      if(check == 150){
        var randomEven = null;
      }

      var bacteria = {x: vertexData[randomEven], y:vertexData[randomEven+1], r:1};
        var ATTRIBUTES = 2;
        var numFans =64;
        var degreePerFan = (2*Math.PI) / numFans;
        var bacteria_vertexData = [bacteria.x, bacteria.y];




    function growth(){

      if(bacteria.r<10){
         requestAnimationFrame(growth);
        for(var a=0;a<randomBacteria;a++){
     bacteria.r += 1;

          for(var i = 0; i <= numFans; i++) {
          var index = ATTRIBUTES * i +2; // there is already 2 items in array
          var angle = degreePerFan * (i);
          bacteria_vertexData[index] = bacteria.x - Math.cos(angle) * bacteria.r;
          bacteria_vertexData[index + 1] = bacteria.y - Math.sin(angle) * bacteria.r;
        }
        var bacteria_vertexDataTyped1 = new Float32Array(bacteria_vertexData);
        console.log(bacteria_vertexData);
        var bacteria_buffer1 = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bacteria_buffer1);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bacteria_vertexDataTyped1, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);


            var program1 =gl.createProgram();
      gl.attachShader(program1,vertextShader);
      gl.attachShader(program1,fragmentShader);
      gl.linkProgram(program1);
      gl.useProgram(program1);
        var bacteria_resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program1, "u_resolution");
        gl.uniform2f(bacteria_resolutionLocation, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        var bacteria_positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program1, "a_position");
      gl.enableVertexAttribArray(bacteria_positionLocation);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(bacteria_positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, ATTRIBUTES * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, 0);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, bacteria_vertexData.length/ATTRIBUTES);
       } 
     }
    }
    growth();
    }
    };
```

Comment: it didnt let me add 3 images so adding the image which shows how the background circle doesnt render and the only case where i can see the increased circle radius animate http://imgur.com/a/WnxI6